# WP Добавление кастомного класса к ссылке меню из админки

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть кастомное меню, которое формируеться хуками в `function.php`

```
/// Класс к ссылке меню
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class', 'filter_nav_menu_css_class', 10, 4);

function filter_nav_menu_link_attributes($atts, $item, $args, $depth)
{
    if ($args->theme_location === 'header_menu') {
        $atts['class'] = 'bl_nav__link';

        if ($item->current) {
            $atts['class'] .= ' active';
        }
    }

    return $atts;
}

add_filter('nav_menu_link_attributes', 'filter_nav_menu_link_attributes', 10, 4);
```

Вопрос - Как необходимо дополнить код, что бы классы которые назначает админ определенному элементу меню из админки (как указано на фото)
[image: WP class]

отображались в элементах меню. По факту каждый пункт меню будет со своим классом, который подтягивает определенную иконку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Рабочий код:

```
/**
 * Filters the CSS classes applied to a menu item's list item element.
 *
 * @param string[] $classes   Array of the CSS classes that are applied to the menu item's `<li>` element.
 * @param WP_Post  $menu_item The current menu item object.
 * @param stdClass $args      An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
 * @param int      $depth     Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
 *
 * @noinspection PhpUnusedParameterInspection
 */
function filter_nav_menu_css_class( $classes, $menu_item, $args, $depth ) {
    if ( 'header_menu' === $args->theme_location ) {
        $classes[] = 'bl_nav__link';

        if ( $menu_item->current ) {
            $classes[] = 'active';
        }
    }

    return $classes;

}

add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class', 'filter_nav_menu_css_class', 10, 4 );
```

У вас проблема в том, что с классами надо работать не в nav_menu_link_attributes, а в nav_menu_css_class. Туда уже автоматом прилетают классы, включая заданные в админке. Прилетают они в виде массива, который надо всего лишь дополнить своими элементами.

Comment: Спасибо, предложеный вариант работает. Есть только проблемка, что в таком виде оно в class li затягивает полностью все WP класси по уполчанию. ( Пример icon-public menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-post menu-item-14 bl_nav__link) Подскажите, пожалуйста как почистить, от мусорных классов?

Comment: Удаляйте ненужные вам классы из массива $classes через array_diff.